# How to install ruby system-wide using rbenv

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

You may think this is a classic "global" command question, but it is not.

I can set ruby globally by this:

```
rbenv global 2.5.1
```

However this makes ruby2.5.1 global for all users but not for the whole system. When an application in same server want to call ruby or access/pipe ruby, they get `command not found` error.

I believe we should have to install or symlink to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or something...

I couldn't find anything regarding to this. How can I make selected ruby version to be seen to other applications?

My only solution is to build ruby myself to system dir but this will conflict with rbenv.

Examples:

- When postfix want to pipe an email to ruby it cannot find ruby even i set global.
- When webmin trying to run a command via ruby it cannot find ruby too.

**Workaround**:

Adding `/root/.rbenv/shims` folder to the `$PATH` on executed script works as expected but in some cases it is not possible to directly modify `$PATH`. **What is my option here?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

rbenv is simply not designed to do support this, you can see the discussion surrounding this within this [Github Issue](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/38). There are many technical considerations to take into account like permissions if you do this. I found another blog post outlining the process - [System Wide Install With rbenv](https://blakewilliams.me/posts/system-wide-rbenv-install). Going to copy it into this answer incase the blog post goes away.

However, in the long run, you may find that it's simply easier to create or use Ruby packages, such as the [BrightBox PPA](https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/) ones.

> **Installing rbenv**
>
> Instead of the usual location of `~/.rbenv` for single installs we'll
>   be installing to `/usr/local`. You can use a different path if you
>   want, but this is what I prefer.
>
> ```
> cd /usr/local
> git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git rbenv
> chgrp -R staff rbenv
> chmod -R g+rwxXs rbenv
> ```
>
> Make sure the users that will use rbenv are part of the group you
>   associated with the rbenv folder.
>
> Now we want to add the following code into each users `~/.profile`,
>   `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.zshenv` depending on the environment. You
>   can also add it in `/etc/skel/.profile` or `/etc/skel/.bash_profile`
>   template files that are copied when new users are created.
>
> ```
> export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
> export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
> eval "$(rbenv init -)"
> ```
>
> **Installing ruby-build (optional)**
>
> Optionally, you can install the ruby-build plugin to save yourself
>   from building it yourself.
>
> ```
> cd /usr/local/rbenv
> mkdir plugins
> cd plugins
> git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
> chgrp -R staff ruby-build
> chmod -R g+rwxs ruby-build
> ```
>
> **Notes**
>
> Now you should have rbenv and optionally ruby-build setup so you can
>   get started installing and using Ruby. This install is the same as the
>   single user install with two exceptions. The global setting applies to
>   all users and single user rbenv installs can "override" the system
>   wide install.
>
> If you have permission issues make sure all the files in the rbenv
>   folder belong to the proper group and that the users trying to use
>   rbenv are also members of the group.