# How to run a Rails application using other user on the server?

Tags: ruby, linux, server, ruby-on-rails-5, redhat

I am working on a website, developed with Ruby on Rails on RedHat server (linux).
Usually i log in to the server with "exemple.user1" and i run the application using the command "rails s". 
[image: Here and exemple]

I created a new user "exemple.user2", when i logged in with it, and run the application using the command "rails s", i got an error "-bash:rails: command not found"

[image]

what i have to do to make it run with other user than "exemple.user1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Ruby Rails is installed per user.
You have to install Ruby and Rails again on the second account.

Or you can make them system-wide, but it is not really advisable.
You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554408/how-to-install-ruby-system-wide-using-rbenv) on how to make those system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you're using ruby version management like RVM?
user2 may not have `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` in the ~/.bashrc

make sure user2 have the correct $PATH by `echo $PATH`, if user2's $PATH doesn't include the ruby and all the gems paths... check what's user1's $PATH, or check it there is any line related to append ruby-related paths in user's .bashrc